# Exception logging in all methods

Tags: c#, .net, exception

We have repository code that looks something like this:

```
public class PieRepository
{

    public void AddCherryPie(string incredientA)
    {
        try{
            ...
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            log("Error in AddCherryPie(" + incredientA + ")");
            throw new Exception("Error in AddCherryPie(" + incredientA + ")", ex);
        }
    }

    public void AddApplePie(string incredientA, string incredientB)
    {
        try{
            ...
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            log("Error in AddApplePie(" + incredientA + "," + incerdientB + ")");
            throw new Exception("Error in AddApplePie(" + incredientA + "," + incredientB ")", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

So this `try -> catch -> log -> throw new` is present in most of repository methods and other important methods in the project.

We had an argument about this today, as I have never seen someone suggest such type of error handling, but the main argument is that we and support need to know exactly what happened, and any other type of exception handling wouldn't give us exactly this...
Could someone tell if this is ok?

**Edit:** Added original exception message when throwing error.

Comment: The code catches the exception and then doesn't use it, instead it throws a new exception which won't contain any useful debug information. The argument of 'we need to know exactly what happened' makes no sense because without the StackTrace etc you can't know exactly what happened. You should at least log the exception somewhere and then present a useful message to the user.

Comment: For the log aspect, you can try NLog or some other 3rd party solutions (I'm very happy with NLog)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never create a new exception., rethrow it using just throw or at least include the original exception as the inner exception. Otherwise the stacktrace is further up the chain is not correct anymore. It will originate where you did `throw new Exception`.

Better is:

```
public class PieRepository
{
    public void AddCherryPie(string incredientA)
    {
        try{
            ...
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            log("Error in AddCherryPie(" + incredientA + ")");
            throw
        }
    }
```

or

```
    public void AddApplePie(string incredientA, string incredientB)
    {
        try{
            ...
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            log("Error in AddApplePie(" + incredientA + "," + incerdientB + ")");
            throw new Exception("Error in AddApplePie(" + incredientA + "," + incredientB ")", ex); // add original exception as inner exception!
        }
    }
}
```

Personally, I would *Really* recommend to just use `throw` instead of `throw new Exception("...", originalException)`. By always throwing away the original exception you cannot decide what to do later on in the flow. What error to present the user? Action could be different for a database error or validation error (like giving message "database unavailable" or "ingredient A not found") than for a programming error.

The overall method is valid. It is good practice to log it early since you then know the arguments of the method and context of the error. By rethrowing you can handle the error in the UI again, by presenting a message to the user or take other actions depending on the type of the exception.

For some thoughts about error message read this: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/12/23/exception-messages-are-for-programmers/

Now, if you really want to do this for every method use Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP, See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). With that kind of technique you can do it using for example an attribute. Use PostSharp for example: http://doc.postsharp.net/exception-handling. Logging shouldn't clutter the code.

Comment: The original exception is included in code, forgot to add it in the pseudocode. I used just `throw` but the argument is that the exception is not friendly enough.

Comment: in my opinion exception messages should not be presented to the user but should depend on the type of exception. What kind of action would you expect a user to take when the error just says "Error in MethodXXX". It doesn't know about the method. Doesn't care either. User want to know whether he could maybe retry or what the side effects of the error are.

Comment: I'd also recommend strongly against throwing the base `Exception` class at all.  You should always use a more specific exception type, otherwise it becomes impossible to write specific catch clauses where you do want to handle exceptions.  I can't think of a good reason to ever throw (or even create) `Exception`.

Comment: also for writing the name of method you can use this    

 var functionName = new StackTrace().GetFrame(0).GetMethod();

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to use exactly the same behavior in every one of your methods, I strongly recommend using an aspect-oriented programming framework.

That way you can define an aspect (attribute), which contains your custom exception handling logic, and avoid having the same boilerplate code in every method.

Your class might look like this if you use aspects:

```
public class PieRepository
{
    [LogExceptions]
    public void AddCherryPie(string incredientA)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And your aspect could look like this:

```
public class LogExceptionsAttribute : OnExceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        // Create a log message, you can access the method info and parameters
    }
}
```

If you attribute your methods to use aspects, the aspects will be called every time the methods execute, so make sure to use a framework that supports compile-time weaving (as opposed to runtime weaving, which has a huge impact on your application's performance).

See http://doc.postsharp.net/exception-handling for an in-depth example.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer, but Peter Bons was first, to bad I cannot mark both as answers :(

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways you can go about this. The simplest is to use the Data property of the Exception class:

```
public void AddApplePie(string incredientA, string incredientB)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Data["IncredientA"] = incredientA;
        ex.Data.Add("IncredientB", incredientB);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a custom exception that contains additional information, then throw that one with the original exception as the inner exception.

To give you an idea, consider the following:

```
public class PieRepositoryException : Exception
{   
    public PieRepositoryException(string message, Exception innerException, params string[] ingredients):base(message, innerException)
    {
        Ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public property string[] Ingredients { get; private set; }
}
```

You can then do this:

```
public void AddApplePie(string incredientA, string incredientB)
{
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new PieRepositoryException("Error adding apple pie.", ex, incredientA, incredientB); 
    }
}
```

Your higher level code can then implement a strategy to either catch particular exceptions, catch generic ones and output all their properties to a log or use formatters to output to the log based on the type.

Comment: In a repository parameters can be everything from int to objects, this is not a really big problem as they all can be represented as strings, but the main idea in the question was how good of an idea is to implement `try -> catch -> log -> throw new ` in all methods.